# I got some wierd bug while building TMX files in Monogame

Tags: monogame, tiled, monogame-extended

Today I tried to implement tilemaps to my game that I'm developing on **Monogame**. Those tilemaps were created by using **Tiled** map editor.

For implementing my tilemaps I used **Monogame Extended**. I installed *Monogame.Extended.Content.Pipline* of version 3.8.0 (latest).

So after those stuff I added my tilemaps (*TMX*) and tilesets (*TSX*) to my Content Pipline Project but after building I got some wierd errors.

**With tilemap**

```
Processor 'TiledMapProcessor' had unexpected failure!

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.get_TransparentBlack()'.
  at MonoGame.Extended.Tiled.Serialization.TiledMapImageContent.get_TransparentColor()
  at MonoGame.Extended.Content.Pipeline.TiledMapProcessor.Process(TiledMapContentItem contentItem, ContentProcessorContext context)
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentProcessor`2.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentProcessor.Process(Object input, ContentProcessorContext context) in /home/runner/work/MonoGame/MonoGame/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline/ContentProcessor.cs:line 60
  at MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Builder.PipelineManager.ProcessContent(PipelineBuildEvent pipelineEvent) in /home/runner/work/MonoGame/MonoGame/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline/Builder/PipelineManager.cs:line 717
```

**Also with tilesets**

```
Processor 'TiledMapTilesetProcessor' had unexpected failure!

System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.get_TransparentBlack()'.
  at MonoGame.Extended.Content.Pipeline.TiledMapTilesetProcessor.Process(TiledMapTilesetContentItem contentItem, ContentProcessorContext context)
  at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.ContentProcessor`2.Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.IContentProcessor.Process(Object input, ContentProcessorContext context) in /home/runner/work/MonoGame/MonoGame/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline/ContentProcessor.cs:line 60
  at MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Builder.PipelineManager.ProcessContent(PipelineBuildEvent pipelineEvent) in /home/runner/work/MonoGame/MonoGame/MonoGame.Framework.Content.Pipeline/Builder/PipelineManager.cs:line 717
```

I tried to search this bug on Internet and even using ChatGPT but nothing gave me result.

I would be greatful for any help!

Comment: [A web search for "missing method get_transparentblack"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=missing+method+get_transparentblack&ia=web) turns up [other users having this same issue, and tips for working around it](https://github.com/craftworkgames/MonoGame.Extended/issues/783)

Comment: Please edit to post your error as formatted text. Some of the [many reasons to post errors/code as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/950488) include making your question more searchable, and more accessible for folks using screen readers or translation software, so you get access to more experts who can help you. We appreciate your help.

Comment: @DMGregory Like I mentioned I didn't find any solution for this problem on Internet. Both downgrading and upgrading to the latest alpha version of Monogame Extended aren't working for me, unfortunetly